# Why wont my modal work after returning to the website?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

For some reason I cannot reuse my modal once I leave the site. In order to make it work you need to clear the cache.

Here is the code for my modal:

```
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-offset-0 col-lg-4">
             <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/london.PNG" alt="London" width="450px">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
                    </div>

                 <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#london">London</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="london" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Leaving Site</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>You are leaving this site, Do you wish to continue?.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <row>
               <div class="col-lg-6">
              <a href="http://www.temp1.absolutehtml.co.uk/" class="btn btn-success" onclick="$('#london').modal('hide')">Yes</a>
              </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
              <a href="http://www.temp1.absolutehtml.co.uk/" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger">No</a>
              </div>
          </row>



      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
                 </div>
          </div>
```

The url is
www.absolutehtml.co.uk/indexnew.html and the section is the templates. I want to be able to open the link in a modal and then close it.

Codepen to full code

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OEZOra

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you're describing. What version of bootstrap are you using? And what browser are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 and chrome

Comment: Ive updated the link was a late night posting and it was the wrong link.

Comment: I still can't reproduce it. Can you provide the full HTML code of your page, including <script> and <link> tags?

Comment: ive updated the post to contain a codepen to the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your codepen, when adding JavaScript libraries jQuery and Boostrap, here's your code :

```
<script async src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Notice the attribute `async`. It tells your browser to keep parsing the document and execute scripts asynchronously. But if you have several scripts loaded with async, there is no way to guarantee which one will be executed first.

The consequence is, depending on several factors (network quality between the client and the cdn, the browser cache, the script size...) the case where the Bootstrap script is executed before the jQuery one may occur randomly.

This result in a fatal error that breaks every other JavaScript on your page (including the JavaScript code that toggles your modal).

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

To fix this, replace `async` by `defer` to guarantee the order in which scripts will be executed by the browser.

```
<script defer src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This way, your browser won't execute the boostrap script before it's done executing the jQuery script.

EDIT : [your updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JZvebX)

[More about async and defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: Thanks for that but its not fixing the issue when the template modals can only be used once. When you visit the link then attempt to use it again its not doing anything.

Comment: @GeniusboyWonder This is odd. Did you clean your cache? I copied all your codepen to my local machine. Used defer instead of async. Clicked yes on the modal and then went back. And it worked. See my edit. I updated your codepen.